# Asp.net Mvc5.1 and BootStrap 3 Add attribute to a Html.ActionLink

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

I would like to have a Html.ActionLink acting as the link:

```
 <a href="http://www.mysite.com" class="screenshot restau" rel="~/Content/Tooltip/MyImage.jpg" >To My Site</a>
```

So I try:

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Accueil", "Index", "Home",new {href="http://www.mysite.com"}, new { @class="screenshot restau" }, new { rel="~/Content/Tooltip/MyImage.jpg"})</li>
```

But so I got an error:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper, string, string, string, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary, System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>)' has some invalid arguments
```

If I remove the href attribute it doesn't work either and I get this as Html rendered:

```
a rel="~/Content/Tooltip/LeSoufflotPatit.jpg" href="/?class=screenshot%20restau">Accueil
```

Where I can see my css class as some encoding problem and I have a strange href

What I'm missing, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to use just 1 new {}

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Accueil", "Index", "Home",new {href="http://www.mysite.com" ,@class="screenshot restau", rel="~/Content/Tooltip/MyImage.jpg"})</li>
```

Also I'm not sure you can use href,because ActionLink generates href for you

Comment: You doubt about the href seems afterward very clever. It doesn't work but anyway with this href problem in mind and a good night I have to find another way. Thanks